# Android Using Application Context Inside Widget For Pending Intent

Tags: android, widget, android-intent

A WidgetProvider button will use a `PendingIntent` to communicate.
Inside the `onUpdate(Context ...)` method of the WidetProvider the following line appears:

```
PendingIntent buttonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, buttonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Which context is being passed in by the widget manager android?

Is it ok to use `context.getApplicationContext()` for the `PendingIntent`? As I have found that the widget freezes are a certain about of time and different application conditions, even though onUpdate gets called. Using `context.getApplicationContext()` seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WidgetProvider.onUpdate()` is called as a result of AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE broadcast. See [source, line 52](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java#l52).

Javadoc of ['BroadcastRerceiver.onReceive()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) says:

```
...you should never perform long-running operations in it...
```

So, check that you are not doing any long running tasks inside `onUpdate()` as this might be the cause of freezes you are experiencing.

Comment: All I am doing is registering a few null broadcast receivers using the application context in order to check the values of some broadcasts.  this is just context.registerReceiver(null, IntentFilter) filter is on broadcast.  I think this is a quick operation?   It seems like the problem was that on some call to onUpdate invalid intents were added to the button.  I verified that the update was getting called and nothing happened.  Finally i switched to context.applicationContext()  for creating pending intent.  Not sure which context passed in and why this might help but it seemed to solve it.

Comment: btw, do you know how one could examine the pending intent added to the button. If it ever locks up again I would like a way to see if the click got thru.

Comment: Poor man's debugger is what I usually use in cases like this: log a line to logcat when click happens.